# Is it possible to feed a tensor to a placeholder?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way to feed a tensor to a placeholder, or a similar mechanism of connecting tensors after they have been defined?

I have been defining my networks in layers, but now I find myself needing to feed an early layer with a tensor from a later layer. This is pseudo code, I apologize if there are errors.

```
...
# rnn layer
...
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(cell, inputs, ...)
...
# fc layer
...
logits = [tf.matmul(output, W_fc)+b_fc for output in outputs]
...
# predictions
...
preds = [to_one_hot(tf.argmax(logit, 1)) for logit in logits]
...
# now I want to connect preds[t] to inputs[t+1]
```

It would be great if inputs[1:] could be placeholders and I could feed preds[:-1] to them.

If there is not a way, the messy approach I intend to use is to loop over time, from the rnn onward, defining all layers for that back propagation through time time step. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use `tf.placeholder`, but in your example you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

#### using  tensorflow.placeholder_with_default ( ...  )

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf

s = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder_with_default( [ [1,2,3,4,5,6] ] , [None , 6])

print s.run ( x )
```